# Why can't OIDC authorization code flow be all back channel?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've been learning OIDC, especially authorization code flow.

The front channel just gets the authorization code, and then sends this to the client's back end code which then makes a back channel call to the identity provider with the authorization code, client and secret.

This is because you don't want the front end knowing the client secret as this is a security issue.

But, why can't the entire flow be back channel only?

Couldn't the front end make a call to its back end with all the necessary params such as scopes etc, then the backend uses the client ID and client secret, to make a call to the identity provider, and then the back end now has the access token and identity token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OIDC (or OpenID Connect) is about authenticating users to a Relying Party (or Client) without divulging the user credentials to that Relying Party. The front channel flow is there to send the users browser off to a Provider that authenticates the user. If the flow was back channel only, the user would have had to provide his/her credentials to the Relying Party first, which defeats its purpose (e.g. LDAP would have been good enough for this).